# Opencv custom codec

Tags: opencv, codec

I use LG's IP AVI Smart Station Codec package for videos I have, but Opencv (VideoCapture) does not open this video files. What should I do?

LG codecs folder contents

ffh264.dll, ffmjpeg.dll, g7xx.dll

Comment: for java; System.loadLibrary(“opencv_ffmpeg310_64”); or System.loadLibrary(“codec_for_opencv.dll”);